# Обсуждение примера частного наследования из книги

Tags: c++

Вомозжно, если кто-то из Вас читал книгу Прата "C++ Primer Plus", и отвечал на вопросы в конце главы, сталкивался со следующим примером:

```
For each of the following sets of classes, indicate whether public or private derivation
is more appropriate for Column B:
A                              B
class Bear                     class PolarBear
class Kitchen                  class Home
class Person                   class Programmer
class Person                   class HorseAndJockey
class Person, class Automobile class Driver
```

Ответы, на этот квиз, из книги, таковые:

class Bear,                     class PolarBear  **public**
class Kitchen                   class Home       **private**  
class Person                    class Programmer **public**
class Person                   class HorseAndJockey **private**  
class Person, class Automobile class Driver         **public for Person, private for Driver**

Я в принципе то согласен, но вот есть парочка вопросов.
Поскольку частное наследование делает все публичные методы (интерфейс) базового класса закрытой областью в классе наследнике (т.е. можно юзать внутри класса, но нельзя вызывать снаружи), возникает парочка вопросов.
К примеру, в классах Kitchen и Home, так уж ли подходит здесь частное наследование?
 Не спорю, отношения между этими двумя классами больше попадает под парадигму отношений *has-a*, нежели *is-a*, но все-таки. 
Что, если я создам, к примеру, экземпляр класса Home и захочу запустить тостер, который находится на кухне? Или посудомоечную машину? Писать для этого новые методы в Home, которые просто будут реализовывать интерфейс кухни (вызывать ее методы)? Как-то не очень удобно.
Или, скажем, HorseAndJockey. Все-таки, Жокей, он как ни крути, а должен иметь в своем интерфейсе методы Личности, так или нет?
Ну и с последним примером так же. Что, для водителя нельзя вызывать методы Person напрямую? И почему Автомобилем я не могу управлять напрямую вызывая методы Automobile из Driver?
Ну как-то так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- У вас возникли правильные вопросы - в этом части `C++ Primer`, к сожалению, пропускает два фундаментальных момента, которые очень важны с практической точки зрения:

> - **[Favor composition over inheritance.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from)**
> - Приватное наследование в `C++` стоит использовать только для выражения отношения `is-implemented-in-terms-of` [`(Effective C++, Issue 42),`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) что на практике встречается достаточно редко.

- Насчет примеров - если вы правильно ответили на вопросы `[1], [3]` и про `class Driver : public Person` в вопросе `[5]`, то можете считать, что с упражнением вы справились.

> - Остальные случаи действительно попадают под отношение `has-a` и их стоит моделировать с помощью композиции - так, кухня является частью дома, водитель может быть частью абстракции "автомобиль" *(или наоборот, смотря как подходить к данной ситуации)*.
> - `HorseAndJockey vs Person` - это не самый лучший пример, поскольку автором вводится некоторая сущность `Jockey,` которая может никак не соответствовать классу `Person`.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо Вам большое. Честно говоря, у меня постоянно при чтении этой книги подобные вопросы возникают, и хочется все время у кого-то спросить, так это или нет, и если так, то почему именно. Да, все-таки по части С++ предо мною еще непочатый край исследований и открытий.

Comment: @pol500, если не ошибаюсь в книге "Философия Java" автор пишет, что всюду где возможно, при конструировании объектов надо предпочитать композицию, а не наследование.

Собственно, в книгах наследованию уделяют так много внимания из-за сложности темы.